# Какая разница между преинкрементом и постинкрементом в цикле ?

Tags: циклы, c++

Интересует различие именно в цикле for/while и тгд. А так знаю что при постинкременте значение переменной используется и только потом инкрементируется и что операция преинкремента возвращает константу.

Comment: Если опирация стоит просто, изолированно ото всего, например
    
    while(true) {
        //...
        i++;
    }
    for(;;i++) {/* ... */}

Разницы между пост- и преинкрементом никакой совершенно.

Comment: а если например так 
while(true) {
    //...
    i++;
    int j = i;
}

здесь переменной j присвоится i или i после постинкремента ?

Comment: Если оператор состоит _только_ из инкремента, для _элементарного типа_, разницы нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

пример:

```
i = 0;
while (cin >> a[i++])
    continue;
```

или то же самое

```
i = -1
while (cin >> a[++i))
    continue;
```

или то же самое

```
i = 0;
while (cin >> a[i])
    ++i // или i++ без разницы.
```

Сам видишь разницу. Всегда можно один способ заменить другим. Следует только отметить только то, что если ты инкеременируешь какой-то объект, для которого определена операция инкременирования, а не переменную типа int, немного быстрее будет работать операция преинкременирования, потому что в таком случае инкременируется сам объект и возвращается ссылка на объект, а при постинкременировании создаётся новый(так назовём, его временный) объект того же типа, новому объекту присваивается значение инкременируемого объекта, инкременируемый объект инкремерируется, и возвращается тот самый временный объект со старым значением инкременируемого объекта. Т.е. в случае с постинкременированием создаётся, копируется и удаляется объект, тогда как в случае с преинкременированием этого не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь разницы никакой. Учите матчасть! Инкрементная и постинкрементная формы имеют различное поведение при операции присаивания, например:
    i = 5;
    j = i++; // в итоге j = 5 а i = 6

Comment: Я не такой уж дебил ... . За ответ спасибо.

Comment: у С++ очень даже интересные штуки творяться... Это все дело еще зависит от компиляторов )